# Perl - How to apply negative lookbehing/lookahead on pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

I have problem to implement my regex. Below is string:

```
my $substitute = q(lalalla = 10..32:1
[thrdddholds]
bbbb = "40..45:1"
cccc = 2..10:5
eqaeaeaea = 5

[bss]
Tad1=3
Nbdfas43p =1..30:1
NbDe524v_1231n= 1);
```

Substitution with pattern:

```
if ($substitute =~ /(?:(?:[\d-\.]+[, ]+)+[\d-\.]+)|([-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*)/) {
  if ($substitute !~ /(")(?:(?:[\d-\.]+[, ]+)+[\d-\.]+)(")/g) {
  $substitute =~ s/([-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*)/"\1"/g;
  }
}
```

My result

```
lalalla = "10..32:1"

[thrdddholds]
bbbb = ""40..45:1""
cccc = "2..10:5"
eqaeaeaea = 5

[bss]
Tad1=3
Nbdfas43p ="1..30:1"
NbDe524v_1231n= 1
```

Problem is in line `bbbb = ""40..45:1""` instead `""` should be `"` so fixed line should look like: `bbbb = "40..45:1"`

All expected result:

```
lalalla = "10..32:1"

[thrdddholds]
bbbb = "40..45:1"
cccc = "2..10:5"
eqaeaeaea = 5

[bss]
Tad1=3
Nbdfas43p ="1..30:1"
NbDe524v_1231n= 1
```

How achieve it? I tried with negative look ahead and behind, but it work only on one char, not all string.

Comment: Perl doesn't use PCRE.

Comment: You forgot to enable warnings.

Comment: What warnings? Okay. I checked this. So what standard of regex use Perl? Own?

Comment: Warnings as in `use warnings;` (and `use strict;`, of course). Perl should have told you something about your code.

Comment: What do you mean, "standard"? There's a POSIX standard for regexes (two of them, actually (basic/extended)), but everyone ignores it. All tools behave slightly differently when it comes to regexes (unless they use the same regex library internally). Perl has its own. PCRE is an independent library (written in C++, I think?) that tries to mimic Perl's regexes.

Answer (score -2):

Try Regex:

```
"*(\d+\.\.\d+(?::\d+)*)"*
```

substituting with:

```
"\1"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuP83q/1)

Comment: Its work. But how do if statement for my example? To do substitiution only when pattern havent " "

Comment: not sure if I understood your question correctly. could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I add ifs statements to my question near my substitution. "IF" should mean when match 1..30:1 without " around.

Comment: if we need to do negative lookbehind and negative look ahead try this `(?<!")\b(\d+\.\.\d+(?::\d+)*)\b(?!")` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuP83q/2)

Comment: with the regex in the comment above, you might not need the if condition

Comment: Work with substitution from my question. But why dont work with this: if `($substitute =~ /(?<!")\b([-\d+\.]*\.\.[-\d+\.]*:[-\d+\.]*)/)` ?

Comment: see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuP83q/3) with the regex inside the if condition. see its explanation: `Match a single character present in the list below [-\d+\.]*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)`

Comment: This is a question about Perl, not sed. Please substitute with `$1` rather than `\1`, which means a single character with a code point of 1.